# Angular Scroll to Next Route when page hits bottom

Tags: angular, scroll, lazy-loading

While scrolling down from the first route, when the page hits the end then automatically it should route to next route. As I have Lazy loaded module, I need them to appear as single page scroll through all routes.

Comment: Why can't you use [anchorScrolling](https://stackblitz.com/edit/solution-anchor-scrolling-myn3gm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.routing.ts)?

Comment: I am afraid that this does not solve my problem

Comment: I have different routes. Each route is a lazy loaded module, these module contains multiple component. So one of the trick which I used was using scroll event navigate to route but didn't seem to work well. Also went through solutions over internet but none helped. Would appreciate for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ways to know when an element is visible in screen:

1.- Listening scroll event

```
import {fromEvent} from 'rxjs'

@ViewChild("elementBottom") element:ElementRef

$obs=fromEvent(window,'scroll').pipe(
   filter(()=>{
     const position = this.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();

    // checking whether fully visible
    return (position.top >= 0 && position.bottom <= window.innerHeight)
   }),
   take(1)
)
```

2.- Using [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

For this you create a directive "stolen" from [Sascha Wolff](https://medium.com/@sascha.wolff) [article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-create-infinite-loading-with-angular-14-and-intersection-observer-3e0e679ade4c) like

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appIntersection]',
})
export class IntersectionDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  observer: IntersectionObserver;
  previousEntry: IntersectionObserverEntry;
  subscription:Subscription=null;
  @Input() rootMargin = '0px 0px 0px 0px';
  @Output() scrollEnd: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor(private el: ElementRef,private router:Router) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription=this.router.events.pipe(
   filter((ev)=>ev instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe(()=>{
      this.previousEntry=null
    })
    this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => {
        const entry=entries.find(x=>x.isIntersecting)
          if (!this.previousEntry?.isIntersecting && entry) {
            this.scrollEnd.emit();
            this.previousEntry = entry;
          }
      },
      {
        rootMargin: this.rootMargin,
        threshold:1
      }
    );

    this.observer.observe(this.el.nativeElement);
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.observer.disconnect();
    this.subscription && this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Now your main.component can be like

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div appIntersection (scrollEnd)="scrollEnd()" style="height:3rem"></div>

export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(private router:Router){}
  scrollEnd()
  {
    switch(this.router.url)
    {
      case "/":
        this.router.navigate(['/company']);
        break;
      case "/company":
        this.router.navigate(['/products']);
        break;
      case "/products":
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dg5zhn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE: See that I enclosed all teh component in a div with the class `whole`

```
.whole{
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

To be sure that we need make a scroll

Comment: But the thing is I am using modules to lazy load the components. Moreover I have a routing module wherein I import those module and route them using lazy loading. Can you help me with this.

Comment: It's the same you use [lazy loading](https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading) or not. (Angular will take a little time to load, but the router works in the same way)

Comment: Thankyou, but the second method i.e  Intersection Observer didn't work. I am sure I have made some mistake. Will try to resolve the same & get back here.

Comment: I have again tried the same, but failed to understand why the 2nd method is not working. Can you please help me out? I will provide the details required.

Comment: Its working, but sometimes it fails to navigate i.e no event is listened when hit bottom of the page. Not understanding why this is happening. Thanks man for helping me out.

Comment: @unlimit, The event (almost teorically) happens when the element where we have the directive pass from not seen to seen fully, try make it a background red, e.g. adding `style="back-ground:'red;border:'1px solid black'"` to see it

Comment: OK. Will try this and revert back